# Android: Separator Line for GridLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

In my application I have a Listview and Each item in a Listview has a GridLayout. 
And I add a custom view to the GridLayout through adapter class. The size of the views that added to GridLayout is not same. It may varies from one view to another view.
My code in getView() adapter is,

```
for (int i = 0,j=0; i < (data.get(position).getItems().size() * 2) && j< (data.get(position).getItems().size()); i=i+2,j++) {
            View childView=getChildView(position, j);
            childView.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
            Log.i("ChildView Height",childView.getLayoutParams().height+" length");
            holder.order_row.addView(childView, i);
            holder.order_row.addView(getItemSeparatorView(minHeight),i+1);
        }

private View getChildView(int pos, int i) {

        //Log.i("position in child", pos + "");

        View child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.order_item, null);
        InnerViewHolder inholder = new InnerViewHolder();
        inholder.name = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.order_name);
        inholder.items = (ListView) child.findViewById(R.id.order_list);

        inholder.name.setText(data.get(pos).getItems().get(i).getItemName()+":");
        inholder.name.setTextColor(itemColor);
        inholder.items.setAdapter(new OrderItemOptionAdapter(context, data
                .get(pos).getItems().get(i).getOptions(),itemColor));
        int size = data.get(pos).getItems().get(i).getOptions().size();
        Log.i("childview", "called" + i+ "size is "+size);
        if (size > 7) {
            child.setLayoutParams(new GridLayout.LayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    260, 80 + (size * 20))));

        } else if(size <=7 && size>=4 ){
            child.setLayoutParams(new GridLayout.LayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    260, 450)));
        } else {
            child.setLayoutParams(new GridLayout.LayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    260, 250)));
        }

        return child;
    }
    public View getItemSeparatorView(int h){
        //Log.i("seperator","called and height is "+h);
        View sep = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_seperator, null);
        sep.setLayoutParams(new GridLayout.LayoutParams(new LayoutParams(2,h)));
        return sep;
    }
```

And My xml code is.

```
<GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/order_row"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:columnCount="6"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
>    </GridLayout>
```

I want to add a separator line which has the maximum height of the childViews.
And In some case the gridlayout may have more than 1 row so the height of the separator view   should change according the max height of the view in a row of GridLayout.

*If I can add all the child views first with index like 0,2,4,etc. And then calculate the max height of the Childviews. After calculate the max height i can able to add the separator views with index like 1,3,5,7etc..*

Please provide me the correct way to do this.
Thanks.

Comment: minHeight=260; I do this app for fixed size android device.

Comment: getChildView() for views to be added in GridLayout

Comment: getItemSeparatorView(int) for separator line view between two childviews

Comment: If I can add all the child views first with index like 0,2,4,etc. And then calculate the max height of the Childviews. After calculate the max height i can able to add the separator views with index like 1,3,5,7etc..

Answer (score -6):

set Verticalspacing and Horizontal spacing in grid view xml file

```
  <GridView
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp" >

    </GridView>
```

I hope it will help you.